# adding attributes for a tag in deserializing xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

My xml has attributes.how can i declare those variables for deserialization.
xml is as follows.

```
<LabelRequest   Test="NO" LabelType="DEFAULT" LabelSubtype="NONE" LabelSize="4x6" ImageFormat="PNG">
 <MailpieceShape>FLAT</MailpieceShape>
 <Services Open="On" />
 <Options mail="off" />
</LabelRequest>
```

I tried like this.

```
  public class Requester
{ 
  public string LabelRequest { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Test { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LabelType { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LabelSubtype { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LabelSize { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ImageFormat { get; set; }
    public string MailpieceShape { get; set; }

}
```

But its showing like there is an error in Xml Document.How should i declare the attributes?

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: without attributes its working fine.but i am adding attributes,its showing an error-"There is an error in XML Document(1,2)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working 100%. I've just changed `mail` property to `Mail` so it correct with naming convetion for properties.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Requester objectToDeserialize;

        using (Stream stream = File.Open("file.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Requester));
            objectToDeserialize = (Requester)deserializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(objectToDeserialize.Test);
        Console.WriteLine(objectToDeserialize.LabelType);
        Console.WriteLine(objectToDeserialize.LabelSubtype);
        Console.WriteLine(objectToDeserialize.LabelSize);
        Console.WriteLine(objectToDeserialize.ImageFormat);
        Console.WriteLine(objectToDeserialize.MailpieceShape);
        Console.WriteLine(objectToDeserialize.Services.Open);
        Console.WriteLine(objectToDeserialize.Options.Mail);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "LabelRequest")]
public class Requester
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Test { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LabelType { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LabelSubtype { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LabelSize { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ImageFormat { get; set; }
    public string MailpieceShape { get; set; }
    public Services Services { get; set; }
    public Options Options { get; set; }
}

public class Services
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Open { get; set; }
}

public class Options
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Mail { get; set; }
}
```

XML for this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LabelRequest Test="NO" LabelType="DEFAULT" LabelSubtype="NONE" LabelSize="4x6" ImageFormat="PNG">
  <MailpieceShape>FLAT</MailpieceShape>
  <Services Open="On" />
  <Options Mail="off" />
</LabelRequest>
```

Comment: i am getting the values of open and mail as null

Comment: Can't be. I tested this code on my pc before pasting it here.

Answer (score 1):

Your class should be like this:

```
    public class LabelRequest
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Test { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LabelType { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LabelSubtype { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LabelSize { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ImageFormat { get; set; }

    public string MailpieceShape { get; set; }

    public Services Services { get; set; }

    public Options Options { get; set; }
}

public class Services
{
    public string Open { get; set; }
}

public class Options
{
    public string mail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yeah ok.what i have to do if have xml like this.please have a look at my edited question

Comment: @sindhujampani, for complex nodes you'll need do declare new classes. You can look here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx), the article is quite integral Answer updated